# google admob ios compilation error: library not found for -lfacebook_ios_sdk

Tags: ios, compiler-errors, admob

I have downloaded the latest Google Mobile Ads SDK (6.7.0). When I integrate it to my Xcode project and compile, I get the following compilation error:

`ld: library not found for -lfacebook_ios_sdk
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

I am using Xcode 5.0.2 with Base SDK iOS 6.1.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Check your library search paths in your build settings.  However, in this case, it appears that the library it can't find is not google mobile ads but facebook_ios_sdk, as mentioned in the error message.